# Spf record processing speed

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf, txt-record

I send email through a service provider smtp server that uses a domain different than mine.

My email client uses smtp1.provider.net to send emails, but usually the message is routed through smtp2.provider.net so, the last sending ip belongs to the last smtp server.

I'm trying to configure my first Spf record keeping in mind two things:

1) I have no direct control over the provider smtp infrastructure so, the ip address or domain name of smtp2.provider.net may change without notice.

2) I've structured the Spf record hoping that the first mechanism evaluated result in a match, avoiding further checks and dns queries on the receiving smtp side.

I'd like to know if the first Spf record may result in a faster processing than the last and simpler one shown below:

```
mydomain.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:<ip of smtp2> ip4:<ip-subnet of smtp2> a:smtp2.provider.net a:smtp1.provider.net include:provider.net a mx -all"

mydomain.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 include:provider.net a mx -all" (contains multiple include)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're emails are being delivered to multiple Email Providers, each one of those providers process SPF Differently.

1. Some ESP will evaluate the entire SPF, if any part of the SPF record does not conform to standards it will just fail the entire thing.
2. Some ESP will evaluate the SPF in order and as soon as a MATCH is found, it short circuits the SPF.

In the event of #2 your first SPF record you listed will be faster.